# Python: how to identify existing field value and avoid updating while writing

Tags: python, csv

I am not sure if the title is appropriate but let me state my problem here in explained manner.

i have a given data set containing weather data. The sample of the data is given as follows.

```
ID,ID_TYPE,OB_DATE,VERSION_NUM,MET_DOMAIN_NAME,OB_END_CTIME,OB_DAY_CNT,SRC_ID,REC_ST_IND,PRCP_AMT,OB_DAY_CNT_Q,PRCP_AMT_Q,METO_STMP_TIME,MIDAS_STMP_ETIME,PRCP_AMT_J
90, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,24109,1011,0,0,6, 2006-01-17 09:04,0,
150, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, DLY3208,900,1,30747,1011,0,0,6, 2006-01-09 13:21,3,
174, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,24775,1011,0.2,0,6, 2006-01-17 09:04,0,
498, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,0, WADRAIN,900,1,1622,1012,0.1,0,1, 2006-01-17 09:04,0,
498, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,31,1622,1022,58.3,0,22576, 2006-03-15 11:41,0,
898, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,0, WADRAIN,900,6,1624,1012,18.5,0,20001, 2006-01-17 09:04,0,
898, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,1624,1022,0.4,0,2576, 2006-03-15 11:41,0,
996, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WAMRAIN,900,31,24953,1011,53.5,0,6, 2006-01-31 13:51,0,
997, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,24953,1011,1.6,0,6, 2006-02-02 12:28,0,
1045, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,1628,1011,1.1,0,6, 2006-01-17 09:04,0,
1103, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,24772,1011,2.5,0,6, 2006-01-17 09:04,0,
```

i have created a code which identifies the date in the given data and produces the `weekday` corresponding to each `date`. the code for the same is given as follows:

```
import re                                           #importing regular expressions
from datetime import datetime as dt                 #importing datetime module

def changedate(ob_date):
    weekday = dt.strptime(ob_date, ' %Y-%m-%d %H:%M').strftime('%A')
    return ob_date + ',' + weekday                                          #defining a function which returns the weekday

csv = open('raindata.csv').read()
headers = re.sub(r'ID,ID_TYPE,OB_DATE,VERSION_NUM,MET_DOMAIN_NAME,OB_END_CTIME,OB_DAY_CNT,SRC_ID,REC_ST_IND,PRCP_AMT,OB_DAY_CNT_Q,PRCP_AMT_Q,METO_STMP_TIME,MIDAS_STMP_ETIME,PRCP_AMT_J'
                 ,'ID,ID_TYPE,OB_DATE,WEEKDAY,VERSION_NUM,MET_DOMAIN_NAME,OB_END_CTIME,OB_DAY_CNT,SRC_ID,REC_ST_IND,PRCP_AMT,OB_DAY_CNT_Q,PRCP_AMT_Q,METO_STMP_TIME,MIDAS_STMP_ETIME,WEEKDAY,PRCP_AMT_J'
                 ,csv)   #creating a pattern to change the header names
writing = re.sub(r'( \d+-\d+-\d+\s\d+:\d+)', lambda m: changedate(m.group()), headers)  #creating a pattern to append the weekdays under the given header names

with open('raindata.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(writing)   #writing the data in a new CSV file
```

The output produced is given as follow:

```
ID,ID_TYPE,OB_DATE,WEEKDAY,VERSION_NUM,MET_DOMAIN_NAME,OB_END_CTIME,OB_DAY_CNT,SRC_ID,REC_ST_IND,PRCP_AMT,OB_DAY_CNT_Q,PRCP_AMT_Q,METO_STMP_TIME,MIDAS_STMP_ETIME,WEEKDAY,PRCP_AMT_J
90, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,Sunday,1, WADRAIN,900,1,24109,1011,0,0,6, 2006-01-17 09:04,Tuesday,0,
150, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,Sunday,1, DLY3208,900,1,30747,1011,0,0,6, 2006-01-09 13:21,Monday,3,
174, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,Sunday,1, WADRAIN,900,1,24775,1011,0.2,0,6, 2006-01-17 09:04,Tuesday,0,
498, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,Sunday,0, WADRAIN,900,1,1622,1012,0.1,0,1, 2006-01-17 09:04,Tuesday,0,
498, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,Sunday,1, WADRAIN,900,31,1622,1022,58.3,0,22576, 2006-03-15 11:41,Wednesday,0,
898, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,Sunday,0, WADRAIN,900,6,1624,1012,18.5,0,20001, 2006-01-17 09:04,Tuesday,0,
898, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,Sunday,1, WADRAIN,900,1,1624,1022,0.4,0,2576, 2006-03-15 11:41,Wednesday,0,
996, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,Sunday,1, WAMRAIN,900,31,24953,1011,53.5,0,6, 2006-01-31 13:51,Tuesday,0,
997, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,Sunday,1, WADRAIN,900,1,24953,1011,1.6,0,6, 2006-02-02 12:28,Thursday,0,
1045, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,Sunday,1, WADRAIN,900,1,1628,1011,1.1,0,6, 2006-01-17 09:04,Tuesday,0,
1103, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,Sunday,1, WADRAIN,900,1,24772,1011,2.5,0,6, 2006-01-17 09:04,Tuesday,0,
1358, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,Sunday,0, WADRAIN,900,11,1633,1012,17.7,0,20001, 2006-01-17 09:04,Tuesday,0,
1358, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,Sunday,1, WADRAIN,900,31,1633,1022,42.5,0,22576, 2006-03-15 11:41,Wednesday,0,
1545, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,Sunday,1, WADRAIN,900,1,1636,1011,2,0,6, 2006-01-17 09:04,Tuesday,0,
1584, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,Sunday,1, WADRAIN,900,1,315,1014,2.4,0,2306, 2006-03-15 11:41,Wednesday,0,
```

The problem with my script is that if i run it again and again then the weekday are appended as many times as i run my code. I want a solution where python can evaluate if there is a weekday in my data then it doesn't produces any appending of weekday again. Moreover my script also falls back when the `OB_TIME` and `MIDAS_STMP_ETIME` have empty fields. So can anyone improve the code top get the correct results.

Thanks in advance and any clarification can be solved in the comment section :)

Comment: Just check whether 'WEEKDAY' is in the header?

Comment: Have you tried setting a condition which says that if the 4th column contains a weekday don't run the script?

Comment: @Farhan.K i have not given any condition. as i am already creating this column by my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will save a lot using the built in [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv
import datetime

with open('raindata.csv') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    field_names = list(csv_reader.fieldnames)
    rows = list(csv_reader)

# insert new column header
if 'WEEKDAY' not in field_names:
    field_names.insert(field_names.index('OB_DATE') + 1, 'WEEKDAY')

with open('raindata.csv', 'w') as file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(file, field_names)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    for row in rows:
        row['WEEKDAY'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['OB_DATE'], ' %Y-%m-%d %H:%M').strftime('%A')
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Result:

```
$ python test.py
ID,ID_TYPE,OB_DATE,WEEKDAY,VERSION_NUM,MET_DOMAIN_NAME,OB_END_CTIME,OB_DAY_CNT,SRC_ID,REC_ST_IND,PRCP_AMT,OB_DAY_CNT_Q,PRCP_AMT_Q,METO_STMP_TIME,MIDAS_STMP_ETIME,PRCP_AMT_J
90, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,Sunday,1, WADRAIN,900,1,24109,1011,0,0,6, 2006-01-17 09:04,0,
150, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,Sunday,1, DLY3208,900,1,30747,1011,0,0,6, 2006-01-09 13:21,3,
```

Comment: @desmond.carros, this is not an implementation of your task, this is an example if how you can use `csv` module for your task. I thought you need to add a `WEEKDAY` column (looking at your `re.sub(...)` expression, though you don't need `re.` here, `str.replace` would be enough). If so, your example input data is wrong -- it already has `WEEKDAY` column. If you read my answer, `get_weekday` is a stub -- you should write your code there.

Comment: okay i think i have given a wrong sample. Let me refine the sample for you. and then can you update the code.?

Comment: Thanks for the updates. the solution is correct, but i want it to append in the same CSV then re running of scripts may again append a weekday field in the given data?

Comment: Then you have to pass to `open('raindata.csv')` to `csv.DictReader`. This site is not for making code for you. You should ask clear small questions and get answers for them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106337/discussion-between-desmond-carros-and-warvariuc).

Answer (score 0):

The `pandas` library is well suited for these kinds of operations.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt

def get_day(ob_date):
    weekday = dt.strptime(ob_date, ' %Y-%m-%d %H:%M').strftime('%A')
    return weekday

df = pd.read_csv('met.csv')
df['WEEKDAY'] = df['OB_DATE'].apply(get_day)
```

You could also use `.apply(get_day)` to other datetime columns using the bracket notation and column name.

Comment: your solution holds true for getting `weekday` values but it fails when the fields are missing. moreover you solution also appends weekday again and again whenever i re run the script.

Comment: moreover i don't want to use any external module for taking out the experiment. I want to use the Base Python for the same

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime as dt


csv_file = open('raindata.csv')
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
field_names = list(csv_reader.fieldnames)
if 'WEEKDAY' in field_names:
    print "data has error"
elif 'RECWEEKDAY' in field_names:
    print "data has error"
else:
    field_names.insert(field_names.index('OB_DATE') + 1, 'WEEKDAY')
    field_names.insert(field_names.index('METO_STMP_TIME') + 1, 'RECWEEKDAY')

    def get_weekday(ob_date):
        return dt.strptime(ob_date, ' %Y-%m-%d %H:%M').strftime('%A')

    output = open('raindata.csv','w')
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(output, field_names)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    for row in csv_reader:
        row['WEEKDAY'] = get_weekday(row['OB_DATE'])
        row['RECWEEKDAY'] = get_weekday(row['METO_STMP_TIME'])
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Solution by the help of @warvariuc